# the paging access of sub-document sorting in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

The trouble is that I don't know how to write the source statements about the paging access of sub-document sorting in `mongodb`. Who can help me?

Comment: Would be a great idea to explain your problem in detail.

Comment: thanks for Ur  suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDb sub-document sort paging access as follow:

```
db.getCollection('Request').aggregate(
                    {$match:{"UserId": 1}},      
                    {$unwind: "$ReceiveRequestList"}, 
                    {$sort:{"ReceiveRequestList.IsStatus": 1, "ReceiveRequestList.CreateTime": 1}}, 
                    {$group: {"_id" : "$_id", "TotalCount":{$sum: 1}, "ReceiveRequestList": {"$push": "$ReceiveRequestList"}  }},

                    {$unwind: "$ReceiveRequestList"},
                    {$skip: 1},
                    {$limit: 1},
                    {$group: {"_id" : "$_id", "ReceiveRequestList": {$push: "$ReceiveRequestList"}, "TotalCount": {$first: "$TotalCount"}   }},
                    {$project: {"_id": 0, "ReceiveRequestList": 1, "TotalCount": 1}
)
```

explain above code:

1. "Request" is tablename
2. "ReceiveRequestList" is sub-document name
3. "$unwind" command will Split sub-document list to many main documents
4. "$sort" is used to sort order by fieldname
5. "$group" is used to Statistics
6. "$skip" and "$limit" is used to paging get data
7. "$project" is used to filter fieldname
   0: represent that do not include the fieldname
   1: represent that include the fieldname

summary:
mongodb can not support sub-document sorting directly, so we need "$unwind" command to split sub-document list to main documents，then sorting main documents(using "$unwind" command generate), finally using "$group" command to merge the main documents as a sub-document list.

**I hope it can help you!**